# can't make loader visible when button is clicked

Tags: html

The loader will not show when button is clicked.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I tried moving the script around with no impact.  The message does change when the button is clicked.  I tried changing the   to  and changed from document.getElementsByName to document.getElementById with no impact.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.loader {
    
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>How To Create A Loader</h2>

<div class="loader" style = "visibility : hidden"></div>  
 <p><button onclick="clickMe(); return false;">Make loader visible</button></p> 
  <div id="message" style="color:green">test to unhide loader</div>  


</body>
<script>
      function clickMe() {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "class"; 
        document.getElementsByClassName("loader").visibility = 'visible';
      }

       
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Also be aware of your button type,  if your button is doing a postback you'll never see the loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors related to the visibility setting.

First one is `document.getElementsByClassName("loader")` returning a list of elements, not just one element. Even though the list contains just one entry, it's still a list. You can get the first entry from a list using the zero index.

The second problem is that in your code you try to set the visibility on an element, but it's actually an attribute of an element's `style`.

Try this:

```js
function clickMe() {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "class";
  document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>How To Create A Loader</h2>

<div class="loader" style="visibility : hidden"></div>
<p><button onclick="clickMe(); return false;">Make loader visible</button></p>
<div id="message" style="color:green">test to unhide loader</div>
```

Comment: That worked!  I thought that was one of my first attempts about 50 tries ago.  Apparently, it wasn't.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.visibility = 'visible';

getElementsByClassName returns a list thus you need to reference which one you want with [0].  also need to set style

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.loader {
    
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>How To Create A Loader</h2>

<div class="loader" style = "visibility : hidden"></div>  
 <p><button onclick="clickMe(); return false;">Make loader visible</button></p> 
  <div id="message" style="color:green">test to unhide loader</div>  


</body>
<script>
      function clickMe() {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "class"; 
      
        document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
      }

       
    </script>

</html>
```